# Apache Pig - Store and Load from RCFiles

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Using an older version of Pig, say 0.11, is it possible to read/write to hdfs using RCFiles?

I know that Pig version 0.14 has support for Optimized RCFiles i.e ORCFiles, but i'd like to stick to using my current pig version i.e 0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Elephant-Bird library (https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/) from Twitter has support for loading and storing RCFiles

The class needed is
RCFilePigStorage (extends PigStorage)

https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/blob/master/rcfile/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/store/RCFilePigStorage.java

This library supports Pig Version 0.8 and above.